# Prove that $\lim_{n\to+ \infty}(g ◦ f)(x) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose f, g : (0,∞) → (0,∞), and let g ◦ f : (0,∞) → (0,∞) be their composition. Suppose also that $\lim_{n\to + \infty} f(x)=+∞$ and $\lim_{n\to+ \infty}g(x)= L \in {\rm I\!R}$.

Prove that $ \lim_{n\to+ \infty}(g ◦ f)(x) = L$

I know people like to see work that's been done, but I am really just having a hard time figuring out even where to start. My intuition is the squeeze theorem, but even just getting this problem off the ground I am having trouble with. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)$ can be made large by choosing $x$ large.  $g(f(x))$ can be made close to $L$ by choosing $f(x)$ large, thus $g(f(x))$ can be made close to $L$ by choosing $x$ large.  I'm not sure what level you're at and what constitutes a "proof" for your class, but this is the idea.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, actually. The class I am taking is just your basic undergraduate real analysis course. I've taken a proofs course before, but I must say, this does not come easy to me.

Comment: Definition. Write everything down in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$, and you would see how to approach.